# Gradle - ProGuard - DuplicateClasses - NineOldAndroids

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I use some libraries/modules for my project.

On two of the libraries there are "**nineoldandroids**" used in the gradle with "**-compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'**" on every library/module !

If I want to crate an APK in Android Studio with "**Build** - **Generate Signed APK**" I get always the "**ProGuard**" error "**duplicateclasses**" with following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':xxxxx:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write
 [F:\Projekte\Android_Studio\xxxx\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\
release\classes.jar] (Can't read 
 [F:\Projekte\Android_Studio\xxxx\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\
Android_Studio\library_SwipeListView\unspecified\libs\
nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] 
(Duplicate zip entry [com/b/a/b.class == nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar:com
/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class]))
```

How can I solve this error?

**SwipeListView**:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

}

**NumberPickerCompat**:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

}

**MainProject**:

```
dependencies {
compile project(':library_CalendarViewCompbat')
compile project(':library_FAB_Menu')
compile project(':library_NumberPickerCompat')
compile project(':library_ReminderDatePicker')
compile project(':library_StickyListHeaders')
compile project(':library_SwipeListView')
compile project(':library_SunDate_Picker')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
compile files('libs/dashclock-api-r1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.
The problem was that **some .jar files** are saved in some "**build**" folders.

This was because I have **migrated** from **Eclipse** with the .jars and have later deleted it and added the compile to gradle.
But I haven't seen that in the "build" folders they are saved too.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude one of the nineoldandroids transitive dependencies from your main project :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library_NumberPickerCompat')
    compile(project(':library_SwipeListView')) {
        // Already present in NumberPickerCompat
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    }

    ...
}
```

Please note the extra parentheses on the second `compile` dependency

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**SwipeListView:**

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

**NumberPickerCompat:**

```
dependencies {

}
```

**MainProject:**

```
dependencies {

    //put nineoldandroids in main project
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    compile project(':library_CalendarViewCompbat')
    compile project(':library_FAB_Menu')
    compile project(':library_NumberPickerCompat')
    compile project(':library_ReminderDatePicker')
    compile project(':library_StickyListHeaders')
    compile project(':library_SwipeListView')
    compile project(':library_SunDate_Picker')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/dashclock-api-r1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
}
```